# How can I make a RecyclerView scroll smoothly?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I have a notes app and the notes are contained in a RecyclerView. When I am close to notes with images attached, the RecyclerView becomes "jerky".
I tried setting `android:nestedScrollingEnabled` to false. It doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Without seeing any code we're not going to be able to help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.